# Android Things static ip or wifi peap

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-things, wifi

I tried to set static ip from command shell but after reboot raspberry lost configuration. 
I also tried to configure the WiFi peap in the wpa_supplicant.conf file but I did not get any results.
Do you have any suggestions on how to solve these problems?

Comment: you should set a static IP on the router it connects to, not the device

Answer (score 0):

I hardly found documentation about this, but it seems like Android Things will only work if its address is given by a DHCP.
Even if you set it manually with the `ifconfig` command, it will return an error and the IP you just set will not be usable...